# How can I use Log4j2 logging on BEAM workers?

Tags: log4j, apache-beam, log4j2, slf4j

I'm trying to use Log4j2 logging implementation together with Slf4j api in the BEAM pipeline. In maven it looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

It works fine locally. Also the logging works fine for the container where I start the pipeline. However, inside the workers this setup causes some issues:

```
Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.LoggingException: log4j-slf4j2-impl cannot be present with log4j-to-slf4j
```

This additional library `log4j-to-slf4j` is not part of my project and it's not listed in dependencies (also not in transitive dependencies). Looks like it's added by BEAM sdk itself. The question is: how can I configure BEAM to use my version of Log4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is easy. Looks like BEAM uses slf4j v1 libs so these dependencies work fine with it and use log4j2 as a backend for logging:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

When we generate a `Beam` project with `2.47.0` version using the [Maven archetype](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/) :

```bash
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.beam \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=beam-sdks-java-maven-archetypes-examples \
    -DarchetypeVersion=2.47.0 \
    -DgroupId=org.example \
    -DartifactId=word-count-beam \
    -Dversion="0.1" \
    -Dpackage=org.apache.beam.examples \
    -DinteractiveMode=false
```

It generate the project with the following dependencies in the `pom.xml` file :

```xml
<properties>
      <beam.version>2.47.0</beam.version>
      <slf4j.version>1.7.30</slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
       <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
       <!-- When loaded at runtime this will wire up slf4j to the JUL backend -->
       <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then in the code, you use `SL4J` as usual in Java projects :

```java
public class TeamLeagueApp {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TeamLeagueApp.class);

    ....
    LOGGER.info("My log");
```

I recommend you using the dependencies and version brought by `Beam` natively to handle logs, in order to prevent some dependencies conflicts and issues.

Comment: My problem is not the logging itself. Slf4j is just the API. I just want to use Log4j2 (v2) as the implementation for it.